# Adjuntar ficheros vía email en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy teniendo problemas para que Laravel me adjunte ficheros que llegan a través de un formulario.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    class MailerController extends Controller
{

    public function mailTo($recipients,$contenido,$subject,$attach=[]){
        /*
            * Mandamos y montamos todo el contenido ✅
            * Grabar el registro de envio mail ❌
        */
        foreach($recipients as $recipient){   
            $mail = new EnvioComunicado($contenido,$subject);
            
            foreach($attach as $adj){
                $mail->attachFromPath($adj);
            }
            Mail::to($recipient)->send($mail);
            // Mail::to($recipient)->send(new EnvioComunicado($contenido,$subject,$attach));
        }
    }
}
```

Mi clase EnvíoComunicado:

```
class EnvioComunicado extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public $contenido,public $subject,public $attach=[])
    {
        //
        $this->attach = $attach;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: $this->subject,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'emails.email',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Y cuando lo llamo, es desde mi controlador que gestiona todo el formulario. La parte de la llamada es:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        // TODO Crear un custom request
        $utilidades = new UtilidadesController();  
        $attach = [];

        // * Control de adjuntos y grabado             
        if(!empty($request->file("files"))){
            $files = [];              
            foreach ($request->file("files") as $key => $file){
                $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(public_path("attachement"),$fileName);
                $attach[]=storage_path($fileName);
                $files[]["name"] = $fileName;
            }
            
        }

        //dd($attach);

        $comunicado = Comunicados::create([
            "id_plantilla"=> $request->plantilla,
            "asunto"=> $utilidades->entitiza($request->asunto,ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-1"),
            "contenido"=> $request->contenido,
            "adjuntos"=> serialize($request->adjuntos),
            "programado"=> $request->programado
        ]);
$plantillaData = new PlantillaController;
            $rutaPlantilla = $plantillaData->givePlantilla($request->plantilla)->ruta_html;
            $htmlEmail = File::get("storage/plantillas/".$rutaPlantilla);
            $htmlEmail = Str::replace("<!--contenido-->",$request->contenido,$htmlEmail);

            $enviaMail = new MailerController;
            
            switch($request->grupo){
                case 'manual':
                    $direcciones = explode("\n",trim(preg_replace("/\r/","",$request->manual)));
                    $direcciones = array_unique($direcciones);
                break;
            }

 $enviaMail->mailTo($direcciones,$htmlEmail,$request->asunto,$attach);
```

Los ficheros se graban bien en la carpeta `public` por lo que entiendo que no es problema de permisos, pero no logro que me adjunte ficheros el email.

Comment: No deberías atachar en la función attachments(): array que al parecer devuelve el arreglo vacio. Nosotros lo atachamos en la notificación public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->markdown(
            'cotizador::cotizacion.mail.presupuesto', ['cliente' => $this->cotizacion->cliente, 'cotizacion' => $this->cotizacion]
        )->attach($this->file)->subject('Presupuesto de Cortinas Solicitado');
        
    }